# How do I add natspec for automatically generated functions?

Tags: solidity

```
contract MyContract {
  /// @dev Total number of coins
  public uint256 totalSupply;
}
```

Solc automatically creates a `totaSupply()` function, however the natspec comment doesn't come through. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.13/natspec-format.html#documentation-example):

> NatSpec currently does NOT apply to public state variables (see [solidity#3418](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3418)), even if they are declared public and therefore do affect the ABI.